# using postMessage in a modal to communicate the parent window

Tags: javascript, reactjs, postmessage

I have a html page that opens a modal using  window.showModalDialog with a React application as the uri:

var retValue = window.showModalDialog ("http://localhost:8080/myreactapp, "dialogWidth:500px; dialogHeight:500px; dialogLeft:300px;");

This react app displays a form and has a data object to contain the form values. When I submit the form
I would the the updated data object to be sent to the parent html page of the modal .

I've been using  the [postmessage api]  (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) for communicating between the parent and the child windows.

In the modal I have:

`window.top.postMessage( message, 'http://localhost:3000/postMessage.html' );`

I've also tried:

`window.parent.postMessage( message, 'http://localhost:3000/postMessage.html' );`

I can communicate from the react app to the parent when I use an iframe but not when using a modal.

The postmessage simply does nothing in modal, there is no error message and no message sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working.

In the html  client I use two test  methods :

```
 function createWindow()
{
 var win = window.open('http://localhost:8080/myreactapp', 'popup', 
'status=
 no,toolbar=no,location=no,
 directories=no,
 resisable=no,
 srollbars=yes,
 width=1050,height=600');

 }

 function createWindowV2() {
if (window.showModalDialog) {
    showModalDialog ("http://localhost:8080/myreactapp", window, "dialogWidth:1000px; dialogHeight:800px; dialogLeft:300px;");

   }
```

}

Then in the popup/modal window :

```
 const [IE, setIE] = useState(false);
 const [chrome, setChrome] = useState(false);
 const [openerWindow, setOpenerWindow] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
   const handler = event => {
    if (typeof event.data !== 'undefined') {
    document.getElementById('received-message').innerHTML = event.data;
    }
    };

   window.addEventListener('message', handler);
   setIE(/*@cc_on!@*/ false || !!document.documentMode);
   setChrome(
  !!window.chrome && (!!window.chrome.webstore || !!window.chrome.runtime)
   );

   setOpenerWindow(window.dialogArguments);

   // clean up
   return () => window.removeEventListener('message', handler);
  }, []);


  const handleSubmit = evt => {
    evt.preventDefault();

   if (IE) {
     openerWindow.postMessage(
      message,
     'http://localhost:3000/postMessage.html'
     );
    } else {
         window.opener.postMessage(
         message,
        'http://localhost:3000/postMessage.html' );
    }
   };
```

Answer (score 0):

`window.showModalDialog` is deprecated in most browsers, so I would suggest using a modal component from a library such as react-bootstrap to achieve the same effect.

Given that, you can check the origin of your target windows to see if they match the origin you're passing in as the target. If they don't match, the message will not be sent.

For example

`window.top.location.origin` should match `'http://localhost:3000/postMessage.html'`

Come to think of it, I've never seen origin specified with the actual leaf page, so maybe your target origin should be `'http://localhost:3000`.